# Erro Ao Atualizar Base de dados com Entity Framework Core Code First

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework-core

Tenho minha domain criada com N objetos e esses objetos são convertidos em tabela no banco de dados, no Entity Framemework Core com Code First. 
Se eu crio o banco com as tabelas ele cria perfeitamente entretanto se a tabela já existir e eu tento atualizar com um novo campo ou com a remoção do campo o comando Update-Database da erro, falando que a tabela já existe(no caso ele verifica a primeira tabela que ele tenta criar se já existir ele da esse erro).
Eu gerei  a consulta e percebi que quando ele gera o scrip o mesmo não vem assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <NOME DA TABELA> {<CAMPOS>}
```

Mas sim assim:

```
CREATE TABLE <NOME DA TABELA> {<CAMPOS>}
```

E eu percebi que a tabela "__EFMigrationsHistory" ele cria como citado no primeiro exemplo.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso ?

```
Update-database -verbose -context Context
Using project '<pacote>'.
Using startup project '<pacote>'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<projeto>\<projeto>\<projeto>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\<sistema>.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\<nome>\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<sistema>\<sistema>\<projeto>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\<sistema>.runtimeconfig.json "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.2.0-preview2-35157\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" database update --context Context --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<sistema>\<projeto>\<sistema>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\<sistema>.dll --startup-assembly C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<sistema>\<projeto>\<sistema>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\<sistema>.dll --project-dir C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<projeto>\<projeto>\<pacote>\ --language C# --working-dir C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<projeto>\<projeto>--root-namespace <sistema>
Using assembly '<pacote A>'.
Using startup assembly '<pacote  B>'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<projeto>\<projeto>\<pacote>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<sistema>\<sistema>\<pacote>'.
Using root namespace '<pacote>'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\<nome>\source\repos\<sistema>\<sistema>\<pacote>\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding IWebHost accessor...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from IWebHost accessor on 'Program'.
Found DbContext 'Context'.
Found DbContext 'ContextLog'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
      The 'bool' property 'Alugado' on entity type 'Apartamento' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used for inserts when the property value is 'null'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
      The 'bool' property 'AlterarSenha' on entity type 'Conta' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used for inserts when the property value is 'null'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
      The 'bool' property 'ContaAtiva' on entity type 'Conta' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used for inserts when the property value is 'null'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
      The 'bool' property 'Logado' on entity type 'Conta' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used for inserts when the property value is 'null'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20601]
      The 'bool' property 'PermissaoValida' on entity type 'PermissaoConta' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used for inserts when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used for inserts when the property value is 'null'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.0-preview2-35157 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

                    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END
                    FROM information_schema.tables
                    WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
Using context 'Context'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly '<pacote>'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly '<pacote>'...
No design-time services were found.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Executed DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "MigrationId", "ProductVersion"
FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory"
ORDER BY "MigrationId";
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT "MigrationId", "ProductVersion"
      FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory"
      ORDER BY "MigrationId";
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20181101021917_FirstMigration'.
Applying migration '20181101021917_FirstMigration'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (112ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "Chat" (
          "Id" bigserial NOT NULL,
          "DataCriacao" timestamp without time zone NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '2018-10-31 23:19:15.721042',
          "DataModificacao" timestamp without time zone NULL,
          "DataInativacao" timestamp without time zone NULL,
          "Status" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          "Conversa" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
          "DataEnvio" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '10/31/2018 23:19:15',
          CONSTRAINT "PK_Chat" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "Chat" already exists
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1012
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1032
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 467
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 332
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1220
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1042
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1025
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Failed executing DbCommand (112ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "Chat" (
    "Id" bigserial NOT NULL,
    "DataCriacao" timestamp without time zone NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '2018-10-31 23:19:15.721042',
    "DataModificacao" timestamp without time zone NULL,
    "DataInativacao" timestamp without time zone NULL,
    "Status" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Conversa" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    "DataEnvio" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '10/31/2018 23:19:15',
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Chat" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "Chat" already exists
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1012
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1032
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 467
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 332
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1220
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1042
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1025
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
42P07: relation "Chat" already exists
```

Answer (score -1):

Preciso saber se você atualizou seus mappings com a alteração que foi feita para sua entidade.

Se sim, você tem que adicionar um novo migration (Add-Migration 'name') e depois dar updade-database (não é obrigatório, mas seu migration irá gerar um repositório que fica mais fácil de ser acompanhado dentro do código fonte, it's up to you);

Comment: Ja adicionei um novo migration, e ele da erro falando que a tabela ja existe, isso usando o banco Postegrees

Comment: Linneker, tenta executar o update-database utilizando na frente o -verbose, desta maneira vamos saber qual migration ele está executando e qual o código SQL que ele está criando. Coloca o resultado na sua pergunta depois.

Comment: Ja editei, mas continua com erro

Comment: O migration, vai inserindo algumas informações no banco de dados , nas suas próprias tabelas. Procure por elas e ache um registro que indica a existência da tabela.

Comment: Eu procurei, só que ele nem chega a inserir esse dado e esse problema esta acontecendo só com postgres com Sql Server vai redondo.

Comment: Pelo que vi no verbose, no trecho 

Applying migration '20181101021917_FirstMigration'.

Esse trecho diz que você está executando um histórico do seu migration basicamente. Força o migration desse ultimo que você gerou (com a alteração da tabela). A meu ver ele está desconsiderando o histórico mesmo com a base montada já.

Comment: Então mas se eu deletar a base e criar novamente ele vem com a alteração do ultimo migration.

Comment: Então, mas sem ter que deletar a base, você rodou o update-database -force -"migration"?

Comment: Eu rodo Update-Database -context DbContext, pois quando coloco -force não aceita o comendo

Comment: Tenta utilizar assim:

**Update-Database –TargetMigration *"nome da sua ultima migration"* **

qualquer coisa, coloca o erro do retorno do comando aqui. Em teoria você não precisaria colocar o context

Comment: Não aceita o comando Update-Database –TargetMigration  <Nome da Ultima Migration>

Comment: Update-Database -TargetMigration:"name_of_migration" é o que está na documentação, da uma olhada ai se não tem alguma coisa diferente disso Linneker